Spring boot in docker: doesnot work uploading images
I have spring boot appliacation for uploading files. When use it local, uploading files work well. When run app in docker, files uploads, but doesnot display. Upload files in directory: /uploads. In docker docker-compose added mount:
  app:
    container_name: example
    build: ./ # configuration options that are applied at build time that we defined in the Dockerfile with relative path
    restart: unless-stopped # configure the restart policy
    env_file: ./.env # specify our .env path that we will create later
    ports:
      - $SPRING_LOCAL_PORT:$SPRING_DOCKER_PORT
    depends_on: # dependency order, mysqldb is started before app
      - db
    volumes:
      - .m2:/root/.m2
      - /uploads:/uploads

Checked with terminal in portainer, directory and file created in container.
But in web, this image doesnot shown:
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8081/uploads/product/6/Screenshot_1.png" class="img-fluid mb-2" alt="white sample">

What else needs to be done to make loading and displaying images work when using spring boot in docker?

Container app's usually load images not into it's own file system, which is expected to be read only but into some Claud storage service like : Amazon S3, Google Claud Storage or Azure Blob Claud. To test locally before deployment you can use something like LocalStack

When you say "it does not display", what does happen?  Do other URL paths work in the application?  What code in your application handles the /uploads HTTP path?  How does it use the /uploads directory in the container?

The issue is resolved. Just to need add handler:
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/uploads/**").addResourceLocations("file:uploads/");
    }
}

